# gca() fails to generate correct figure_id

Tags: scilab

I can not get Scilab to properly respond to which graph window I have selected by mouse click using gca() function. Each time I click on a different window with the mouse I want it to respond by printing a 0 or 1 or 2 for the figure_id, but this program keeps printing figure_id = 2.

I use a double right click to exit from the loop.

I am using Scilab 5.4.0 on a W7 box. Please help me with my faulty logic.

```
x=[0:0.1:2*%pi];
clf(0);
p0=scf(0);
p0.figure_position=[0,0];
plot(sin(x));
xname("First Plot)");

clf(1);
p1=scf(1);
p1.figure_position=[30,30];
plot(sin(2*x));
xname('Second Plot');

clf(2);
p2=scf(2);
p2.figure_position=[60,60];
plot(sin(3*x));
xname('Third Plot');

while (1) do  //until CTRl-d is hit
  [b,xc,yc]=xclick(); //wait til mouse click
  a=gcf();
  scf(a.figure_id);
  mprintf ('You have clicked on graph %d\n',a.figure_id);   //display graph number
  //code to manipulate selected graph here//
  if (b==12) | (b==-1000) then,  //double right click to escape
    break;
  end;
end;  

mprintf('DONE\n');
```

Comment: Actually, I meant gcf() fails to give correct figure_id, not gca() as I wrote in the title.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

I think gcf() documentation is not as clear, it probably has the same behaviour as gce(). From [the docs of gce()](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.4.0/en_US/gce.html):

> This routine returns the handle of the last created (and still existent) entity.

### Solution

You could use the window identity (iwin) returned by [xclick](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.4.0/en_US/xclick.html).

```
[ibutton,xcoord,yxcoord,iwin,cbmenu]=xclick([flag])
```

### Working example

If I update your code like this, it works:

```
while (1) do  //until CTRl-d is hit
  [b,xc,yc,iwin]=xclick(); //wait til mouse click
  scf(iwin);
  mprintf ('You have clicked on graph %d\n',iwin);   //display graph number
  //code to manipulate selected graph here//
  if (b==12) | (b==-1000) then,  //double right click to escape
    break;
  end;
end;
```